# Dynamic WHERE injection via AddWithValue not working in MySQLData

Tags: c#, mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to add a dynamic where based on API call values by adding it via `MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue` but those are ignored and just return the data without that filter.

My query contains tag values like `WHERE TYPE <> 'PR' @data @negozi ...`

Then i populate tags with values like this:

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT SUM(IF(TIPODOC_PA = 'SCONTRINO' OR TIPODOC_PA = 'FATTURA', (IMPORTOPAG_PA - RESTO_PA), 0)) AS TOTPAG, DESCRPAG_PA, RISCPAG_PA, TIMESTAMP(DATA_PA, ORA_PA) AS DATA FROM pagamenti WHERE TIPODOC_PA <> 'VE' AND DESCRPAG_PA <> 'PR' AND DESCRPAG_PA <> 'NR' AND DESCRPAG_PA <> 'FC' AND DATA_PA BETWEEN @start AND @end AND @negozi GROUP BY DESCRPAG_PA ORDER BY TIMESTAMP(DATA_PA, ORA_PA)"

Using cn As New MySqlConnection(DB.getConnectionString(database))
    cn.Open()
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, cn)
        If dataInizio.Equals(dataFine) And Not periodo.Equals("giorno") Then
            Select Case periodo
                Case "anno"
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", New Date(dataInizio.Year, 1, 1))
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", New Date(dataFine.Year, 1, 1))
                Case "mese"
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", New Date(dataInizio.Year, dataInizio.Month, 1))
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", New Date(dataFine.Year, dataFine.Month, Date.DaysInMonth(dataFine.Year, dataFine.Month)))
            End Select
        Else
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", dataInizio)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", dataFine)
        End If
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@negozi", $"{negozi}")

        Try
            Using reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                Return ConvertReader(reader)
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return New List(Of Totale)
        End Try
    End Using
```

In debug the Else statment is executed so the full query should be like `WHERE TYPE <> 'PR' AND DATA_PA BETWEEN '2022-02-03' AND '2022-02-03' AND (NPV_PA, NCASSA_PA) IN ((0, 1)) ...`

But it seems that cmd for @data and @negozi is not even added..

C# answers are welcome.

Table schema:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `02878100342`.`pagamenti`;
CREATE TABLE  `02878100342`.`pagamenti` (
  `NPV_PA` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `NCASSA_PA` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `TIPODOC_PA` varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',
  `TIPOPAG_PA` varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',
  `DESCRPAG_PA` varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',
  `RISCPAG_PA` int(1) default '0',
  `DATA_PA` date NOT NULL default '2001-01-01',
  `ORA_PA` time default '00:00:00',
  `AZZ_PA` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '0000',
  `NSC_PA` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `ID_PA` int(30) NOT NULL default '0',
  `IMPORTODOC_PA` float(10,3) default '0.000',
  `IMPORTOPAG_PA` float(10,3) default '0.000',
  `RESTO_PA` float(10,3) default '0.000',
  `OPERATORE_PA` int(10) default '0',
  `CODICEBUONO_PA` varchar(250) default '',
  `IDTICKET_PA` int(11) default '0',
  `TIPOOPER_PA` varchar(250) default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  USING BTREE (`NPV_PA`,`NCASSA_PA`,`TIPODOC_PA`,`DATA_PA`,`AZZ_PA`,`NSC_PA`,`ID_PA`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

EDIT:
thanks to all comments i've changed the code as following, the decision of concatenating `negozi` inside query was taken as that data is dynamic and could contain LOT of combinations, that data is yet SQL formatted and after CLIENT send the filter i format it for SQL so it should't be exposed to SQL injections.

```
Public Shared Function TotalePagamenti(database As String, filter As ModelConfig.Config, Optional periodo As String = "giorno") As List(Of Totale)
    Dim dataInizio As Date = Date.Parse(filter.data.inizio)
    Dim dataFine As Date = Date.Parse(filter.data.fine)
    Dim negozi As String = ModelConfig.QueryParametri(filter.config, "PA")

    Dim query As String = $"SELECT SUM(IF(TIPODOC_PA = 'SCONTRINO' OR TIPODOC_PA = 'FATTURA', (IMPORTOPAG_PA - RESTO_PA), 0)) AS TOTPAG, DESCRPAG_PA, RISCPAG_PA, TIMESTAMP(DATA_PA, ORA_PA) AS DATA FROM pagamenti WHERE TIPODOC_PA <> 'VE' AND DESCRPAG_PA <> 'PR' AND DESCRPAG_PA <> 'NR' AND DESCRPAG_PA <> 'FC' AND DATA_PA BETWEEN @start AND @end AND {negozi} GROUP BY DESCRPAG_PA ORDER BY TIMESTAMP(DATA_PA, ORA_PA)"

    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(DB.getConnectionString(database))
        cn.Open()
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, cn)
            If dataInizio.Equals(dataFine) And Not periodo.Equals("giorno") Then
                Select Case periodo
                    Case "anno"
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", Format(New Date(dataInizio.Year, 1, 1), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", Format(New Date(dataFine.Year, 1, 1), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
                    Case "mese"
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", Format(New Date(dataInizio.Year, dataInizio.Month, 1), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", Format(New Date(dataFine.Year, dataFine.Month, Date.DaysInMonth(dataFine.Year, dataFine.Month)), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
                End Select
            Else
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", Format(dataInizio, "yyyy-MM-dd"))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", Format(dataFine, "yyyy-MM-dd"))
            End If

            Try
                Using reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    Return ConvertReader(reader)
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return New List(Of Totale)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using

End Function
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Parameterized queries don't use string interpolation, nor do they need casting. Parameters behave the same way function parameters work in .NET - you simply pass the actual strongly typed value you want. That's why they're fast and prevent SQL injection

Comment: If your query actually contains `WHERE TYPE <> 'PR' @data @negozi ` you'd get a MySQL error because that's invalid syntax. It's no different than writing `WHERE TYPE <> 'PR' 'POTATO' 'BANANA'`. A valid condition would be `WHERE TYPE <> @type`

Comment: Besides, it looks like all you need is a simple `WHERE DATA_PA BETWEEN @start ANDS @end` with the parameters `@start` and `@end` calculated by the client in advance with *DateTime values*, not strings. Instead of `YEAR(DATA_PA)` which *can't* use indexes on `DATA_PA`, calculate the year start and end dates as DateTime values and pass these to the query

Comment: The SQL code fragment cannot be provided as a parameter value. Concatenate in your code then provide complete SQL text to MySQL. PS. *AddWithValue* inserts the value as solid string literal, i.e. the provided value is quoted which makes it not code but the string-type value.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the `YEAR(DATA_PA)` was added as i have three filters where i can see data by day, month and year IF the startDate is equals to endDate and year filter is selected (2020-02-03 / 2020-02-03) i need to show the data FOR the whole year by using only `WHERE DATA_PA BETWEEN @start AND @end` won't work

Comment: Anyway i get that i can't use `AddWithValue` for that kind of concatenation so i will find a way to just put that WHERE directly in query like `WHERE DATA_PA BETWEEN @start ANDS @end` by changing `DATA_PA` with `YEAR(DATA_PA)` with an IIF

Comment: While how should i behave with `@negozi` as the value is dynamic and returns the columns and values where i should search for like `(NPV_PA, NCASSA_PA) IN ((0, 1))`?

Comment: @NiceToMytyuk don't use concatenation at all. That's how you get SQL injection attacks. In any case, you don't need IIF or any kind of string manipulation in your query. The values can be calculated on the client. Even if you do use string concatenation (don't), you can calculate the final strings on the client. You gain *nothing but problems* if you try to convert and concatenate dates as strings in SQL

Comment: `While how should i behave with` you never posted the actual query so it's impossible to say. As long as you keep thinking of parameters as string interpolation, you won't be able to write a correct query, much less a working one. Parameters are *function* parameters. They never become part of the query. The server sees the query and compiles it into an execution plan that accepts some parameters. What you end up with is something equivalent to a compiled program. You can pass values to it through parameters, but that won't change the program.

Comment: How about you show us what is your actual query and table schema so we can improve it

Comment: That's why you avoid SQL injection with parameters. No matter what a string parameter contains, it's always treated as an external string value and never changes the already compiled execution plan.

Comment: I've just added the query and table schema

Comment: I've just updated the code by using only DATA_PA by adding parameters like `@start` and `@end`

Comment: So what is `negozi` supposed to contain

Comment: @Charlieface negozi contains a string like `(NPV_PA, NCASSA_PA) IN ((0, 1))` but it can be `(NPV_PA) IN ((0))` or `(NPV_PA, NCASSA_PA) IN ((0, 1), (1, 1), (1,2))` and other variations.. 
I probably should just concatenate it back in query string as i was doing before

Comment: You can't do that: parameters are not code, they are data, so it's just a big string blob. You need to do something like `AND ((@NPV_PA IS NOT NULL AND @NCASSA_PA IS NOT NULL AND (NPV_PA, NCASSA_PA) IN (@NPV_PA, @NCASSA_PA)) OR (@NPV_PA IS NULL AND NCASSA_PA = @NCASSA_PA) OR (@NCASSA_PA IS NULL AND NPV_PA = @NPV_PA))` and pass in both variables

Comment: @Charlieface but i don't know how many `@NCASSA_PA` and how many `@NPV_PA` i will have, NPV are shops and NCASSA are POS which belong to that shops and some can have 10 shops where each have more than 10 POS

Comment: Then you will need to dynamically construct your query, but adding in numbered parameters `@NCASSA_PA1` `@NCASSA_PA2` etc then passing in each one as a separate parameter

Comment: @Charlieface will it play a significant role even in performance (idk if AddWithValue has any performance plus) or by doing so will just prevent SQL injection?

Comment: Most likely yes it will help performance, because the server will cache a plan for every combination of parameter *quantities* ever used, rather than every parameter *value* ever used (so up to 10 plans per parameter if you only ever pass max 10 parameters). And SQL injection is not just about security, it's also about correctness: your query will be more *correct* and less likely to have syntax errors if you use parameters